# Iterators to read and process file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, iterator, iterable

Suppose I have a class `Point` and a function to process `Point` instances

```
class Point { private final int x, y; ... } 
...
void handlePoints(Iterable<Point> points) { for (Point p: points) {...} }
```

Now I would like to read `points` from a file. Each line of the file contains two numbers, so I have a function ("factory method") to create a `point` from a line.

```
Point makePoint(String line) { ... }
```

What should I do now? I can write a function to read the file to a list of `points` and call the `handlePoints` function.

```
List<Point> readPoints(BufferedReader reader) {...} // use makePoint here

void handlePoints(BufferedReader reader) {
   List<Point> points = readPoints(reader); 
   handlePoints(points);
}
```

Unfortunately this function does not seem particularly elegant since it creates an unnecessary list of points in memory.

Wouldn't it be better to use *iterators* ?

```
void handlePoints(Iterator<Point> points) {...}

Iterator<Point> readPoints(BufferedReader reader) {...} // use makePoint here

void handlePoints(BufferedReader reader) {
   Iterator<Point> points = readPoints(reader); 
   handlePoints(points);
}
```

Does it make sense? Won't be this code too "noisy" in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need to have all points in memory, think of something more along these lines:

```
while (reader.ready())
{
  String line = reader.readLine();
  Point point = makePoint(line);
  handlePoint(point);
}
```

How to do this with an iterator and handlePoints: (code for handling exceptions to be added)

```
class PointIterator implements Iterator<Point>
{
  BufferedReader reader;
  PointIterator(BufferedReader myReader) { reader = myReader; };
  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() { return myReader.ready(); };
  @Override
  public Point next() { return makePoint(myReader.readLine()); };
  @Override
  public void remove()
  { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove not supported!"); };
}
```

And because `handlePoints` takes an `Iterable`:

```
class PointIterable implements Iterable<Point>
{
  BufferedReader reader;
  public PointIterable(BufferedReader myReader) { reader = myReader; };
  @Override
  public Iterator<Point> iterator() { return new PointIterator(reader); }
}
```

To use:

```
handlePoints(new PointIterable(reader));
```

Comment: I would like to _reuse_ `handlePoints`, which handles all points together.

Comment: If you don't mind adding it to your dependencies, then Apache Commons IO provides `FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8")` method that returns a `LineIterator`. You must close the LineIterator once you're done. Mapping the line to your Java object is still done as above. See here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

From a memory point of view, you won't really save any memory by using iterators - I'm guessing you'll be reading all the points into memory, so they'll all have to be stored somehow.

An iterator isn't a different collection type: it is simply a different way of iterating through a collection.  For example, you could go `list.iterator()` to get an iterator to loop through your list (or any collection).

The choice of what collection to use to hold all the points in memory is the one that will affect memory (eg. `ArrayList` vs. `LinkedList`).

Comment: I would like to create an `iterator`, which reads a line on `next` and converts it to a `Point` instance.

Comment: @Michael What if the file is invalid (contains rubbish data or does not end correctly)?  Most of the time, I read in an entire file before processing to ensure the file and all its data is valid.  Unless you have a very large number of points, you shouldn't run into any significant memory problems.  Otherwise, you would create your own class which implements the `Iterator` interface, takes the `File` in the constructor and reads the next line in the `next()` method

Answer (score 1):

Just read once from file and have it in memory instead of reading every time from file

```
List<Points> points ;

public List<Point> readPoints(BufferedReader reader) {
     if(points == null) {
        points = new ArrayList();
        // read from file and populate 
        points.add(point) ;
     }
 return points;
}
```

Comment: What if I do not want to read the whole file in memory before handling points ? It looks like a waste of resources for me.

Comment: I dont have any idea. better you can have it in a db then read it